# Update database when session of server JBOSS expires

Tags: jboss, richfaces, seam

I'm using Java, hibernate, SEAM  and Richfaces.

I saved in database a register indicating that the user is login, now i need save in database the moment when the session of server expire. 
I implemented a class that implements HttpSessionListener. I put in the method sessionDestroyed some like the next:

```
            ...
            historia.setFechafinal(new Date());
    historia.setGlosa("test");
    historia.setTiempo("tiempo");
    entityManager.persist(historia);   
            ...
```

When i want to persist the object historia an error is throwed. This should be because the component entityManager just not exist because the session has expired.

How can i write in database after the session is expired? I'm rookie in this subject.

Thank youu

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Seam's Run As feature. We use it for some scheduled processes that run in the background when there is no logged in user.

http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.2.Final/reference/en-US/html/security.html#d0e13810

Answer (score 0):

You can use an observer for this, the method will be fired whenever an http session is destroyed

```
@In User user; //User stored in session scope

@Observer("org.jboss.seam.preDestroyContext.SESSION")
public void userSessionDestroy(){

    //do something with User here

}
```